# Select rows when they contain certain string using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame below:

```
Acct <- c(1001, 1002, 1003)
Tran <- c(01, 02, "ALL")
Group <- c(01, 01, 02)
DF1 <- data.frame(Acct, Tran, Group)
```

Now I need to select the rows where "ALL" shows up. The result should look like:

```
 Acct |  Tran  | Group
 1003 |   ALL  |  2
```

One thing to mention is that "ALL" can be in any column (not just "Tran") and there may be any number of columns.

Comment: A quick and dirty way is, `DF1 <- subset(DF1, DF1[,1] == "ALL" | DF1[,2] == "ALL" | DF1[,3] == "ALL" )`. Thinking of a better way though.

Comment: Use `grepl` to match for the string and `colnames(DF1)` to cycle through all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DF1 == "ALL"` to get a logical matrix to find `ALL`.  Then we can take the `rowSums()` of that matrix and keep the ones where the sum is not zero.

```
DF1[rowSums(DF1 == "ALL") != 0, ]
#   Acct Tran Group
# 3 1003  ALL     2
```

Comment: would this be too controversial? `DF1[!!rowSums(DF1 == "ALL"),]`

Comment: Some people do that.  But I don't :)

Comment: Mind if I play through?

Answer (score 3):

Use this line:

```
apply(DF1 == "ALL",1,any)
```

This will result in a T/F vector that corresponds to the rows that contain at least one "ALL"

`DF1 == "ALL"` gives:

```
> DF1 == "ALL"
      Acct  Tran Group
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

By using apply, as stated above, you get:

```
> apply(DF1 == "ALL",1,any)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And if you want the rows:

```
> select <- apply(DF1 == "ALL",1,any)
> DF1[select,]

  Acct Tran Group
3 1003  ALL     2
```